# Guice binding not done with @Named annotation

Tags: java, annotations, guice, named

I have the following constructor

```
@Inject
public MyClass(Provider<TestClass> testProvider, @Named("myName") String name) {
  //constructor stuff
}
```

My module:

```
@Provides
@Named("myName")
public String getName(SomeObject object) {
    return object.getName();
}
```

The problem is that Guice doesn't do the binding.

**Now if I remove the `@Named` annotation, it works. The `getName()` method is succesfully called.** When adding the `@Named` annotation though, `getName()` is never called, and my constructor ends up being injected with an empty string.

Only one of my methods annotated with`@Provides` returns a `String`, but I'd still like to name it since `String` is a pretty common object that could be injected.

I have also tried the binding within the `configure()` method (as per the documentation, but still nothing.

Anyone know what I'm missing? I checked the documentation to no avail.

EDIT: I'm sure that my imports are correct

Comment: The code that you have looks perfectly reasonable; you are using `Named` correctly. Are you 100% sure that this isn't a case of stale build artifacts or unsaved files?

Comment: Just double check your imports of `Named` annotation.

Comment: These are my imports:
`import com.google.inject.name.Named;`

Very weird. I'm going to try some more troubleshooting. Maybe something wrong with my environment

Comment: Please post an [mcve], the code as posted looks correct and the answer below proves we cannot reproduce it. There's something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. Here is the code I used to verify (guice 4.0):

```
package guice;

import com.google.inject.*;
import com.google.inject.name.Named;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Guice.createInjector(new MyModule()).getInstance(MyClass.class);
    }
}

class MyClass {
    @Inject
    public MyClass(Provider<TestClass> testProvider, @Named("myName") String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("myName")
    public String getName(SomeObject object) {
        return object.getName();
    }
}

class SomeObject {
    public String getName() {
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}

class TestClass {
}
```

Prints "helloWorld" as expected.